# Check if multiple UIScrollViews have been created

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm having a problem with my UIScrollView after and API Call, I was wondering if there is a way to check how many scrollViews are being loaded while I navigate to a viewController.

This is the code that I use to set up the scrollview for the viewController

```
[self.imageScroller removeFromSuperview];
[self.seperatorView removeFromSuperview];
[self.containerView removeFromSuperview];
[self.pagedScrollViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.pagedScrollViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.pagedScrollViewController removeFromParentViewController];
[self.pagedScrollViewController didMoveToParentViewController:nil]



self.pagedScrollViewController = [[PagedScrollViewController alloc]initWithModel:self.model];
[self addChildViewController:self.pagedScrollViewController];
self.pagedScrollViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.frame;
[self.containerView addSubview:self.pagedScrollViewController.view];
[self.pagedScrollViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I want to be able to track how many times the scrollview is being added on, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this after you've set up all your views:

```
int scrollViewCount = 0;
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        scrollViewCount += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `subviews` which returns array of subview in view.

```
let subview = self.view.subviews
for view in subview {
      if view is UIScrollView {
          // your code her
      }
}
```

For Objective c

```
NSArray *arraySubView = [self.view subviews];
for (UIView *subView in arraySubView) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]) {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. The code in the question is Objective-C. Please post answers in the correct language.

Answer (score -1):

Add 2 lines to you viewControllers `viewDidAppear` function as such

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("ChildViewController: ", self.childViewControllers)
    print("Subviews: ", self.view.subviews)
}
```

You should see a list of view controllers and views in your console output.

Check how many instances of scrollView there are.

---

Alternatively, once the viewController has loaded, have a look in the view hierarchy inspector:

[View Heirarchy inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqYyi.png)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecKxI.png)

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. The code in the question is Objective-C. Please post answers in the correct language.